# Macro to find duplicates in a column

Tags: vba, excel

On my worksheet duplicates may be present in column "P". I have to iterate column P, and if any duplicate occurs, then I have to check one condition in column A & B. Please help me out how to find the duplicate column through iteration using a macro in vba code.

This is my code:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set Rng = Range(Range("P11"), Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cel In Rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.Value) > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("dupli")
    End If
Next cel
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Your code is working I don't see any issues. MsgBox pops up on every duplicate.